# Tigase-XMPP Message Packet with Custom Elements or Attributes

Tags: java, python, xmpp, smack, tigase

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" to="5410037:testingmine@muc.app.smsall.pk" type="groupchat" from="5410037@app.smsall.pk/Smack" id="104">
    <body>AaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAAaaaaaaa</body>
          <properties xmlns="http://www.jivesoftware.com/xmlns/xmpp/properties">
              <property>
                  <name>role</name>
                  <value type="string">visitor</value>
              </property>
            </properties>
```

i want to send packet in this format to Client end. but i am unable to send message in above message

Answer (score 0):

Tigase allows you to include anything in the message packet. It does not look at it and it does not change anything. It just let anything go to the destination. What is the exact problem that you are unable to include this custom element in Message?
What you mean by, you are unable to send such message?

Comment: Thankyou for your Reply. 
actually i am adding different attributes in it 
and add new child like
<reply>150</reply>
from server to smack , 

but on client side <reply> is not found